# запуск кода в консоли webstorm

Tags: webstorm

Всем привет! Решил попробовать webstrom после VS code и столкнулся с проблемой, как запустить выделенный участок кода в консоли Webstorm? В VS ПКМ => run code.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. В WebStorm такой функциональности нет. Можно запустить `js` файл, используя **Run** в контекстном меню файла. Кроме того, можно использовать [scratch files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2022.2/scratches.html)

Еще я могу порекомендовать попробовать [Quokka](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9667-quokka) плагин - он позволяет увидеть результат выполнения кода прямо в редакторе

Comment: Спасибо за инфо.